# Heapsort in Python

Tags: python, sorting, heap

Please review the following in-place implementation of Heapsort in Python:

```
def heapsort(l):
    def plunge(l, i, n):
        lchild = 2 * i + 1
        while lchild < n:
            rchild = lchild + 1
            if rchild < n and l[lchild] < l[rchild]:
                child = rchild
            else:
                child = lchild

            if l[i] > l[child]: break

            l[i], l[child] = l[child], l[i]
            i, lchild = child, 2 * child + 1

    for i in range(len(l) // 2, -1, -1):
        plunge(l, i, len(l))

    for i in range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1):
        l[0], l[i] = l[i], l[0]
        plunge(l, 0, i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly good, only minor improvements are  possible:

**Use a conditional *expression* in place of a *statement***

A conditional statement, like the one you used may execute two completely different branches, instead a conditional expression can only return a value. This simplifies and shortens code a bit:

```
if rchild < n and l[lchild] < l[rchild]:
    child = rchild
else:
    child = lchild
```

Becomes:

```
child = rchild if rchild < n and l[lchild] < l[rchild] else lchild
```

To make it clear that you are just deciding what the value of `child` should be and nothing else.

**Give nice names to public arguments**

`l` is one letter long and is easily confused with `1`, at least at small font sizes. Formal parameters names are the first form of documentation and should be given though. For example I suggest `list_` or `xs` (a FP convention).

**Write an additional helper: `heapify`**

Both Wikipedia and Rosetta Code make use of the `heapify` helper, writing it into your code will make it more readable by making it similar to these descriptions.

Also the additional function will make it more clear that a heap is being created at first and then the actual sorted-list construction begins by taking elements from the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Details :

**Idiom**

It seems like `sift_down` is a more common name than `plunge`. It might be a good option to use the usual vocabulary.

**Reversed loop**

Probably a personal preference but I find `range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1)` pretty hard to understand at first and I'd rather read `reversed(range(len(l)))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
        rchild = lchild + 1
        if rchild < n and l[lchild] < l[rchild]:
            child = rchild
        else:
            child = lchild
```

This caught my eye because `rchild` is only ever used here.  What if we inline it, then see if we can refactor differently?

```
if lchild + 1 < n and l[lchild] < l[lchild+1]:
    child = lchild + 1
else:
    child = lchild
```

...is the straight in-lining.  So now refactor:

```
child = lchild
if lchild + 1 < n and l[lchild] < l[lchild+1]:
    child += 1
```

or maybe do it in reverse:

```
child = lchild + 1 # see if right child is usable
if child >= n or l[lchild] >= l[child]:
    # not usable, fall back to left child
    child = lchild
```

..which brings me to my next comment: your lack of comments. Just like choosing good names, comments can fill in the gaps and elucidate *why* something is done, from a summary point of view, since the code itself explains *what* is being done.